# How to code an action trigger with treetop?

Tags: ruby, treetop

I'm trying to have some bit of code running each time the parser recognises a token.

Let's say

```
grammar FooBar

  rule start
    (foo "\n")+
  end

  rule foo
    stuff_i_want:([a-z]+) {
       puts "Hi there I found: #{stuff_i_want.text_value}"
     }
  end

end
```

The idea here would be to have this `puts` action execute each time the `foo` token is found. Coded as is, it does not work as it is triggered only once (at the class loading time) and of course `stuff_i_want.text_value` does not exist then.

Any idea? Is it even possible? The lack of documentation on the library does not make it easy to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure what I did to deserve the downvote.

Anyway, here is the solution I used:

node_extension.rb

```
module Crawlable

  def crawl *args
    continue = true
    continue = action(*args) if respond_to? :action

    return if !continue || elements.nil?

    elements.each do |elt|
      elt.crawl(*args)
    end
  end

end

# reopen the SyntaxNode class and include the module to add the functionality
class Treetop::Runtime::SyntaxNode

  include Crawlable

end
```

then all is left is to define a `action(*args)` method on each node you want to trigger an effect on and have to start the crawling on the top parser node (the one returned by the parse call

```
parse_tree = FooBarParser.new.parse "mycontent"
parse_tree.crawl # add optional parameters for context/state
```

The optional parameters are passed to each `action` method. You can also return a falsey value (`false` or `nil`) in action in order to stop the subtree crawling.

```
grammar FooBar

  rule start
    (foo "\n")+
  end

  rule foo
    stuff_i_want:([a-z]+) {
       def action
         puts "Hi there I found: #{stuff_i_want.text_value}"

         false
       end
     }
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a simpler solution than the one you can up with. I can't see why you would need open up the `SyntaxNode` class in order to get the functionality that you want. All you need to do is traverse the nodes a little bit more (unless I'm not understanding what you're trying to accomplish).

Here's an example:

```
require 'treetop'

Treetop.load_from_string DATA.read

parser = FooBarParser.new

parser.parse("hello\nok\nmorestuff\n").action

__END__
grammar FooBar
  rule start
     (foo "\n")+
     {
        def action
           elements.each {|e| e.elements[0].action }
        end
     }
  end

  rule foo
    stuff_i_want:([a-z]+)
    {
       def action
          puts "Hi there I found: #{stuff_i_want.text_value}"
       end
    }
  end
end

# => Hi there I found: hello
#    Hi there I found: ok
#    Hi there I found: morestuff
```

Comment: Good point, it can be really simple. However the files I am working with have a lot of intermediary syntax nodes that would require recursively calling `action` resulting in a lot of code duplication. I believe my solution is a bit more flexible. But thanks for your input :)

Comment: Makes sense, that's kind of a clever way of handling it.